# Pygame installed but won't import

Tags: python, pip, pygame

A month ago I installed pygame and wrote a lot of working programs using it.  Now I come to run those programs again and I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\ESOL Games\Level 1.py", line 3, in <module>
        import pygame
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I've used pip freeze:

```
C:\Users\User>pip3 freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.8.0
bs4==0.0.1
cycler==0.10.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
jdcal==1.4.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.1.1
numpy==1.17.2
openpyxl==2.6.3
Pillow==6.1.0
pygame==1.9.6
pyparsing==2.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.3
```

and tried to pip and got

```
C:\Users\User>python -m pip install pygame

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in 
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.9.6)
```

So I fully believe pygame is installed, so why will it not import?  I have not changed the directories of any of the previously working programs and I've not moved Idle either.

Why can't it find pygame module?

Comment: Try moving it from directory `lib` to `Lib\site-packages`

Comment: Common cause is that one has more than one Python installation and runs the code with the wrong one.

Comment: @Sid it appears to already be in site-packages, and if it were not there then something went very wrong with the installer. In general it is a bad idea to alter the python directory manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if you have more than one python installed on your system.

You can cross check by from command line type `where python` and in the python file running 
type the below code

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

check if both the pythons are same.

If not you should export the path of the python to which your pygame package is installed

Comment: I got 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\pythonw.exe' from python and C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe from the command line.   They seen different.  do I have to re-install pygame with 32 bit version?

Comment: So you have a 32 bit and a 64 bit python this causes the conflict. All you need is to export the python path of the python which has pygame installed and it should work